# About file I/O in python

Tags: python, file-io

I want to read a txt file and store it as a list of string. This is a way that I come up with myself. It looks really clumsy. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks.

```
import re
import urllib2
import re
import numpy as np
url=('http://quant-econ.net/_downloads/graph1.txt')
response= urllib2.urlopen(url)
txt= response.read()
f=open('graph1.txt','w')
f.write(txt)
f.close()
f=open('graph1.txt','r')
nodes=f.readlines()
```

I tried the solutions provided below, but they all actually return something different from my previous code. 
 This is string produced by split()

```
    'node0, node1 0.04, node8 11.11, node14 72.21'
```

This is what my code produce

```
    'node0, node1 0.04, node8 11.11, node14 72.21\n'
```

The problem is without the'\n' when I try process the string list it will confront some index error.
 " row = index[0] IndexError: list index out of range "

```
for node in nodes:
    index = re.findall('(?<=node)\w+',node)
    index = map(int,index)
    row = index[0]
    del index[0]
```

Comment: This is an example of the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're trying to do is "read a txt file and store it as a list of string"s split by newlines. And you know how to read a file, so it's the splitting you need to know about. So your title should be "Splitting String by Newlines" and heck while you have a great title like that, why not try "splitting string python" in Google and voila.

Comment: I was doing  an exercise provided by a python course online. Since the course uses this fashion to process the file ( it does it locally), I want to do something similar. If I simply use spilt() my codes will run into error.

Comment: @Kaifan: I suspect you're using `split` (or its results) wrongly, rather than it being unsuitable for your purpose. Consider posting a separate question to debug that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), `response` is already a file-like object: you should be able to do `response.readlines()`.

For those problems where you do need to create an intermediate file like this, though, you want to use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.StringIO)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). So:

```
nodes = response.read().split("\n")
```

EDIT: Alternatively if you want to avoid `\r\n` newlines, use [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

```
nodes = response.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: It's actually working differently from my previous code, I test it

Comment: You may have `\r\n`s. See my update. Also, [Hurkyl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539491/1556332) is correct and you should look at that, though you should keep `split` in mind if you're ever doing something similar not from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
url=('http://quant-econ.net/_downloads/graph1.txt')
response= urllib2.urlopen(url)
txt= response.read()
with open('graph1.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
nodes=txt.split("\n")
```

If you don't want the file, this should work:

```
url=('http://quant-econ.net/_downloads/graph1.txt')
response= urllib2.urlopen(url)
txt= response.read()
nodes=txt.split("\n")
```

Comment: I don't think OP actually wanted to make the file, they just mistakenly used it to access `readlines`.